# DataGridViewComboBoxCell shows list just before its row is being removed

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell

Whenever I try to remove a row that contains a DataGridViewComboBoxCell, it drops down its list of items for a fraction of a second before the row is removed. I'm not sure how I can prevent this from happening and would like some insight as to why this might be happening. If I have multiple rows that are being deleted, each row shows the drop down list one after the other for just a split second so this could become quite an issue when removing many rows at once.

Here is where I am removing the rows

```
    for (int i = 1; i < emptyRows.Count; i++)
    {
         this.LoadRulesDataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(emptyRows.ElementAt(i));
    }
    this.LoadRulesDataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    this.LoadRulesDataGridView.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
    this.LoadRulesSaveButton.Enabled = false;
    this.AddRuleRadioButton.Enabled = true;
    this.EditRuleRadioButton.Enabled = true;
    this.RemoveRuleRadioButton.Enabled = true;
    this.AddRuleRadioButton.Checked = false;
    this.EditRuleRadioButton.Checked = false;
    this.RemoveRuleRadioButton.Checked = false;
    this.CancelRuleChangeButton.Enabled = false;
    rowCt = this.LoadRulesDataGridView.RowCount;
```

Please let me know if I should show any additional code/information. Thank you!

Comment: Can you remove the items first, then remove the row..?

Comment: I guess I could do that but it seems like it would be doing more work having to remove the items before I can remove the row. Also, it seems that this only happens when I select an item in the Combobox and immediately try to remove the row without clicking out of the Combobox. Would it be acceptable to possibly force the datagrid to focus on a different cell right before it removes the row?